# Visualforce currency euro

Tags: visualforce, formatting, currency

I need to display currency. This field is Roll-up summary of formula fields with return type 'Number'

```
<apex:outputText value="{0, number, currency}">
    <apex:param value="{!Invoice.Amount__c}" />
</apex:outputText>
```

But this shows amount like this in html: **$150.00**

I need there to be **euro** instead of **dollar**.

Comment: if `Amount__c` is currency field then use `<apex:outpputField>`. No need to format.. ALso below ans you need to add `$` as well..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<apex:outputText value="{0, number, ###,###,###,##0.00}">
    <apex:param value="{!Invoice.Amount__c}" />
</apex:outputText>&euro;
```

This worked

& + euro; is for €

Comment: is there any documentation on the underlying mechanism? I need to remove the currency sign and have comma as the decimal separator!

Answer (score 0):

```
<apex:outputText rendered="{!IF(ISNULL(Invoice.Amount__c),false,true)}" value="€ "/>                     
<apex:outputField value="{!Invoice.Amount__c}"/>
```

It works perfect for me for large number values.